# Question on geometrical proof of Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, algebra-precalculus

The following image is from [Geometric Series Proofs: An Annotated Bibliography](http://www41.homepage.villanova.edu/robert.styer/Bouncingball/geometric_series_3.htm).

[image]

Please explain why it is said that:

> "$ON$ is the limit of the sum $1+x+\dots$."

Thank you.

Edit: I guess what through me off was the word "limit"!

Comment: If anyone is interested, several years ago I managed to trace this approach back to Milutin Milankovitch [Milankovitsch], [Eine graphische darstellung der geometrischen progressionen](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015037931717#view=1up;seq=341), **Zeitschrift für mathematischen und naturwissenschaftlichen** 40 (1909), 329. I do not know whether this idea had been published earlier than 1909. In the 1950s Constantin P. Orloff published several follow-up papers on this in a Yugoslavian journal.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I appreciate the historical detail.

Comment: As a follow-up to my comment 9 years ago, a couple of years ago (but I only came across it now) Volume 28 (1960) of **The Mathematics Student** journal was put into the internet archive, and on pp. 149-159 there is a paper in English by Orloff -- [*Geometrical theory of series*](https://archive.org/details/aclcpl00000552a1359/page/148) (MR 26 #513; Zbl 141.06202).

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro. Thank you for following up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the horizontal lines of length $1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots$ union to form a line of length $ON$.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to travel the horizontal distance from $O$ to $N$. The easiest way is to go via the line $ON$. Alternatively, you could follow the staircase, only counting the movement in the horizontal direction. The first stair has horizontal movement $1$, the second has horizontal movement $x$, and so on. However, once you've arrived at $N$, it shouldn't matter which way you went, the distances are the same. Therefore (the length of the line segment) $ON$ is the same as the limit of the sum $1 + x + x^2 + \dots$

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to the question. If anyone objects I'll delete it.

I came across this trying to find an alternative expression for $\Delta$ in the picture. I thought it looked kinda nice. Similar to the picture above but not exactly the same.
[image: Geometric series]

The length marked as $\Delta$ in the picture is of course simply: $1-\cos{(\beta-\phi)}$.
Looking for an alternative way to calculate $\Delta$ we get the geometric series:

First approximate $\Delta$ as $\Delta_1$. Now we have to subtract the red part in the picture.
Going over to the other side we see $\Delta_2$ contains the length of that red part but has an additional part (the green part in the picture). If we subtract that and repeat this process infinitely we must get $\Delta$.

This results in :

$1-\cos{(\beta-\phi)}=\sin^2{(\beta-\phi)}\left\{ 1-\cos{(\beta-\phi)} +\cos^2{(\beta-\phi)} -\cos^3{(\beta-\phi)} + \cdots \right\} \implies $

$ \frac{1-\cos{(\beta-\phi)}}{\sin^2{(\beta-\phi)}} = \frac{1-\cos{(\beta-\phi)}}{1-\cos^2{(\beta-\phi)}}= \frac{1-\cos{(\beta-\phi)}}{(1+\cos{(\beta-\phi)})(1-\cos{(\beta-\phi)})} = $

$ \frac{1}{1+\cos{(\beta-\phi)} }=  1-\cos{(\beta-\phi)} +\cos^2{(\beta-\phi)} -\cos^3{(\beta-\phi)} + \cdots $

The geometric series.

Comment: Thanks for posting, I guess its too complex for me to get at the moment.

Comment: @NoChance I didn't completely work out the calculations. But it's fairly easy if you know where to look. I know it's a very old post, but if you're still interested let me know. In that case I'll work it out in a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks for willing to help, I will give it a try and may call on your help if you have time, cheers!