# Geometric explanation as to why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^n}$ converges to $\frac{1}{x-1}$?

Tags: summation, fractions

Is there any simple, preferrably geometric, explanation as to why the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^n}$$
converges to
$\frac{1}{x-1}$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series has a few pictures

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483575/question-on-geometrical-proof-of-geometric. Ok?

Comment: g3nuine.Looks like a nice proof. :))

Comment: @PeterSzilas Youre right, its a really nice explanation, sadly I cant accept your comment as answer

Comment: g3nuine.No worry, thanks for your kind words, Peter